# Android button styling does not work for different states

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to style a button with different colors for different states. The coloring (and border radius) works for normal state, but not for `state_pressed="true"`. What can be wrong with my code?

This is the button element:

```
<Button
            android:text="@string/login_button_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/loginbtn"
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

And this one is `loginbtn.xml` in drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#27ae60"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#2ecc71"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to swap the order of your definition as Android picks up the first one that matches, in this case the one without a state defined. Move it to be last:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#2ecc71"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#27ae60"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```